# What are the best practices for returning arbitrary data from an ASP.NET MVC or ASP.NET Web API

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, view

I am building an asp.net (MVC/Web API) application where I will be returning arbitrary data from a view, and the type of data is not known at design time.

Specifically, the user will specify some URI, and my back end will fetch that uri.  The data returned might be a straight text/html web page, or it could return an RSS feed with a text/rss+xml content type, or it might return a JSON payload, etc.  I won't know the format of the data until runtime, after I fetch the data and inspect the content-type.

My objective (for all intents and purposes - irrelevant detail omitted) is to echo that payload back to the user.  I will of course set the proper content type in the response as well as any relevant headers (like cookies) that were in the original response.

What is the best practice for returning the data from the controller action to  accommodate this?  If I were using ASP.NET Web API for example, could I just send (and how?) an arbitrary blob (I use 'blob' for lack of a better term - what I mean is that I will echo the payload of the http response I got when I made the call to the resource) back to the client (of course with the content-type set properly)?

In summary my specific questions are:

1. Should I use ASP.NET MVC or ASP.NET Web API to accomplish this?
2. If ASP.NET Web API (I assuming that is the proper direction), how do I echo an arbitrary stream (I say stream rather than string, because it could be binary) of data (of which I do not know the content-type until runtime) to the client?

Comment: Return the data with a Mime Type, and let the consumer figure it out?

Comment: I mean how do I properly create a view/layout?

Comment: View/Layout is for HTML pages.

Comment: Right - so I am asking how to do this. I updated my question to clarify. Essentially I don't know how to handle in the controller (at least).

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're asking. You don't know how to return a specific view from a controller? Or you don't know how to pass a model to a view? Or you don't know how to use `ViewBag`/`ViewData`? You need to narrow the question down so that it's clear what you're asking.

Comment: @mason I don't know how to do it for a data type that isn't known until execution time.

Comment: I think you just return the object you want.  If you're returning a JSON payload, it's not going to go into a View, unless the view is calling the URL specifically to get the payload (via Javascript).  In other words, you're creating a REST endpoint, not a View.

Comment: It's still not clear to me what you're trying to accomplish. A view needs to know something about the objects it might receive in order to know how to display the object. You can't just pass arbitrary data types to a view.

Comment: @mason - I am trying to return arbitrary data whose data type isn't known until I grab the data from elsewhere at execution time. Maybe an approach for me is to simply output an arbitrary stream of data, independent of any particular view type. So for example if it turns out to be a web page that will be returned, I would just set content type to text/html and then spit out the html. Can I tell a controller action: "hey controller action, here's a strong, just spit it out"?

Comment: @robert You said: "I think you just return the object you want.  If you're returning a JSON payload, it's not going to go into a View, unless the view is calling the URL specifically to get the payload (via Javascript).  In other words, you're creating a REST endpoint, not a View."  Great point, that was my mental gap. I am thinking in terms of mvc views rather than in terms of api end points as you said. If I thought about this in a Web API mindset I could just return an arbitrary data type...

Comment: So... Think in terms of a Web API mindset?

Comment: Yes. Where I thought you were going with your comment was stop thinking in terms of asp.net mvc views and start thinking about it as a rest endpoint, hence "asp.net web api". I put quotes because I am referring to asp.net web api as the technology name -> http://www.asp.net/web-api

Comment: You've now explained your situation better so I understand your goal, but I don't understand what your question is? What's the part you're stuck on?

Comment: @mason - I substantially reworded the question to clarify this.  If you already read my revised version, please check out the last paragraph as I just made another modification 2 seconds ago.

Comment: @mason - I added even more specific questions at the end of the question.

Comment: I described in my answer how content negotiation works and how you can override the default formatter. Doesn't that answer your question?

Comment: @mason - I literally don't know how to return this *arbitrary* data from the controller action itself.

Comment: You're making it more complicated than it is. Inspect the request to see what content type it wants. MVC can handle this. If it expects a file, return a FileResult. If it expects to be redirected somewhere, return a RedirectResult. If it expects a view that your server should provide, return a View. All of those inherit from ActionResult.

Comment: @mason Don't mistake the appearance of me making this more complicated than it is for me being ignorant in the subject, which is really what's going on. :)  Can you edit your answer to focus more on the "how" aspect?  That's ultimately how I reworded the question based on your comments.  Your answer (as-is) makes total sense to me but I can't select it as accepted because it is addressing a much higher level point.

Comment: Start writing code. It should come pretty quick. Look at the Request. Inspect the headers or URL to decode what the user is requesting and what format. Have a series of conditionals that return the requested content using a class that inherits from ActionResult. If you get stuck on a specific part, show your code.